# add each class for each parent li in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html structure is like this

```
 <ul>
   <li>items1</li>
   <li>items2
       <ul>
          <li>items2.1</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>items3
      <ul>
          <li>items3.1</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>items4</li>
</ul>
```

I want to add classes for each parent li like below, using JavaScript is there any possibility to do this?

```
<ul>
       <li class="a">items1</li>
       <li class="b">items2
           <ul>
              <li>items2.1</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="c">items3
          <ul>
              <li>items3.1</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="d">items4</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Javascript only or jQuery

Comment: any one, no problem @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var letters = "abcd";

$("ul").first().children().each(function(index, el)
{
    $(el).addClass(letters[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `not()` filter and `addClass(function)`

```js
$('li').not('li li').addClass(function(i) {
  return String.fromCharCode(i + 97)
})
```

```css
.a {color:red}
.b {color:orange}
.c {color:green}
.d {color:blue}
li li {color:black}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>items1</li>
  <li>items2
    <ul>
      <li>items2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>items3
    <ul>
      <li>items3.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>items4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there could be n number of list items, we can use: `String.fromCharCode(97 + index)` to get the letter (up to z).

```
$("ul").first().children("li").each((index, item) => {
  const letterFromIndex = String.fromCharCode(97 + index);
  let $item = $(item);
  $item.addClass(letterFromIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want add different names for the li u can use this code also

```
var names = ["ab", "bc", "cd", "de"];
$("ul").first().children().each(function(index, el)
{
   $(el).addClass(names[index]);
});
```